# SQL Query with "between" on Alias column with multiple ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

I have alias column from case condition on two columns, and i need to apply between with more than one ranges, i tried `Alias between 10 and 1000 OR Alias between 2000 and 4000` it's taking too much time to execute. please suggest the right way or alternate way.

My query:

```
select X.Id, X.Name
from TableX X
where ((CASE WHEN X.a ='True' THEN X.Id  ELSE X.PId END) between 0 and 1000
    OR (CASE WHEN X.a ='True' THEN X.Id  ELSE X.PId END) between 2000 and 4000)
```

Comment: saaduu Did you look at my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Re-write without `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select X.Id, X.Name
from TableX X
where (X.a = 'True'
       AND (X.Id between 0 and 1000 OR X.Id between 2000 and 4000))
   OR (X.a <> 'True'
       AND (X.PId between 0 and 1000 OR X.PId between 2000 and 4000))
```

Are TableX.Id and TableX.PId indexed?

Comment: @saaduu, tip of today: create indexes!

Comment: is this way only works good only on indexed columns  or what ??

Comment: Original query, this query and the others will need those indexes!

Comment: I'd guess my solution is better. As a general rule, avoid case in where clauses (and ON clauses.)

Comment: I agree that case should be avoided in where clauses.. but won't it perform still perform better then OR?

Comment: @Yossi, do you think so? I'd be a bit surprised. But that depends on the optimizer, and I don't know the SQL Server optimizer well enough. In some way, this case is an or, just trickier to optimize... Compare the execution plans, run some (full-scale) tests and let us know!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using OR like this:

```
select X.Id, X.Name
from TableX X
where (CASE WHEN X.a ='True' THEN X.Id  ELSE X.PId END) between 0 and 4000
    and not (CASE WHEN X.a ='True' THEN X.Id  ELSE X.PId END) between 1001 and 1999
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cteTab as
(
  select X.Id, X.Name, CASE WHEN X.a ='True' THEN X.Id  ELSE X.PId END as InRange
  from TableX X
)
select X.Id, X.Name
from cteTab X
where x.InRange between 0 and 1000
    OR x.InRange between 2000 and 4000
```

Comment: Please, also provide a short explanation.